# What could cause the ampersand-colon block shortcut to SILENTLY fail, jumping out two stack frames?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

While working on a Rails app and investigating a bug, I narrowed it down to the following situation, where line AAA would cause `events` to return nil, running no code after points XXX or YYYY, but line BBB worked as expected. I switched back and forth several times making a clean environment every time, and it always behaved the same odd way.

Ruby 2.5.0, haven't tried downgrading yet but I suspect the issue was present in 2.3 (I skipped 2.4 with this app).

```
# this is the method that has the issue when called. It's in a PORO service object instantiated in a helper method & called from a Rails view.
def events
  @events ||= begin
    events = []
    # some code building up events
    events << :whatever if fulfillment.ready_to_process?
    #XXX -- execution never reaches here with #AAA. But no error is thrown, and events returns nil
    # some more code building up events
  end
end

# Fulfillment & LineItem are ActiveRecords
class Fulfillment
  def ready_to_process?
    # some "return false if" assertions
    result = line_items.any?(&:fulfillment_needed?) #AAA
    result = line_items.any?{ |line_item| line_item.fulfillment_needed? } #BBB
    # YYY -- exececution never reaches here with #AAA
    result
  end
end

class LineItem
  def fulfillment_needed?
    # various assertions
    true
  end
end
```

EDIT: note that in the context where the bug was appearing, fulfillment_needed? was always true.

EDIT 2: actually, I found another something in fulfillment_needed? that can toggle the bug:

```
class LineItem
  has_many :vendor_line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def fulfillment_needed?
    return true if vendor_line_items.empty? # Displays the bug, AAA fails but BBB works
    return true # Does not display the bug AAA && BBB work
  end
end
```

`vendor_line_items.empty?` behaves normally elsewhere.

Comment: Pardom the basic question, but how do you know the execution didn't reach that point? Did you try puts statements or breakpoints?

Comment: @MichaelJohnston : I don't see, how AAA or BBB could possibly be different, unless someone would have fiddled with `to_proc` (which is invoked implicitly in AAA). You say that execution enters `ready_to_process?` but never reaches the `return`. What happens instead? Does it raise an exception or does it just hang forever?

Comment: it neither hangs nor raises an exception. `ready_to_process?` doesn't return (according to puts statements). `events` doesn't execute past XXX, and also it return either nil (before I added a bunch of log statemens) or an empty array -- impossible from a lexical reading of the code  (the stuff before the `ready_to_process` call adds elements to @events )

Comment: I haven't used a debugger on it yet, I'm a logger more than a debugger type, and I run my app through heroku local so it'll take a bit of work to get it setup to be able to use byebug. I use the '&:' form in tons of other places, and have for years and haven't seen anything like this before.

Comment: the only reference to Symbol#to_proc I can find in my app/gems is in [ruby-ole](https://github.com/aquasync/ruby-ole/blob/04d986e244e3fb5865e84050465dc386add57fff/lib/ole/support.rb)